# how to get prompt user input(set /p) under FOR /F Loop

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to store the user input and store in a text file while under for /f loop sequence...

text1.txt(data)

```
Title1
Title2
Title3
```

code:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "delims=" %%a in (text1.txt) do (
    echo Group Name: %%a
    set /p d1="Enter genre:"
    echo.
    echo %%a
    echo %d1%
    echo %d1%>>text2.txt
)
:end
```

but the return output is "ECHO off" on %d1%, can anyone help me with this.

text2.txt

```
Anime
Horror
Comedy
```

I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) since you are setting *and* reading variables in the same block of code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in (text1.txt) do (
    echo Group Name: %%a
    set /p d1="Enter genre: "
    echo.
    echo %%a
    echo !d1!
    echo !d1!>>text2.txt
)
```

`enabledelayedexpansion` is only half the job. You still have to surround the variables which are set inside the loop with `!...!` instead of `%...%`.